# Is it possible to write activity to my Google-fit account using Python?

Tags: python, google-fit, google-fit-api

**Context:**

There's [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hypearth.flibble.app) app, called, **Fit as**, which adds activity to your Google fit account, but it looks like it's based on **real activity**, such as mocking the GPS location or the device accelerometer.

There's also [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.bubson.stepme) app, called **Step Me**, which also adds activity to your Google fit account, but it's instantly. The app devs itself claim it to add data from now, to the past. (Which I think is based on maybe an API or Framework to add data to Google fit).

**What I'm searching for:**

A way to add data like **Step Me** does, but with Python.

**What I already know it's possible to do:**

Using [this](https://gist.github.com/cedricbonhomme/a8c96f1aeb41393dadf6) code as example, it's possible to get data from the API, like this:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import httplib2
from datetime import datetime
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read'
DATA_SOURCE = "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
DATA_SET = "1051700038292387000-1451700038292387000"
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

def retrieve_data():
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    fitness_service = build('fitness', 'v1', http=http)

    return fitness_service.users().dataSources(). \
              datasets(). \
              get(userId='me', dataSourceId=DATA_SOURCE, datasetId=DATA_SET). \
              execute()

def nanoseconds(nanotime):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(nanotime // 1000000000)
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dataset = retrieve_data()
    with open('dataset.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(dataset, outfile)

    last_point = dataset["point"][-1]
    print("Start time:", nanoseconds(int(last_point.get("startTimeNanos", 0))))
    print("End time:", nanoseconds(int(last_point.get("endTimeNanos", 0))))
    print("Data type:", last_point.get("dataTypeName", None))
    print("Steps:", last_point["value"][0].get("intVal", None))
```

And, yes, I can find [some](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-fit) [examples](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistoryApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistoryapi/MainActivity.java) in [java](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history), but it doesn't help when I need to use it on a python program itself.

Comment: The Java examples you are looking at are from the android SDK. The code above is calling fit using the [Rest API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest). See also the Rest API reference, e.g. [listing data sources](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list).